# Getting the BIM 360 Scene ID in Unity

Tags: autodesk-forge

How can I retrieve the scene ID without using postman?

I’m using the Forge toolkit for Unity and the 2legged auth. Is it absolutely necessary to use postman?

Comment: Postman is just a way to make api calls, you could make the same calls in Unity using any Restclient

Answer (score 0):

As Samuel said, Postman is just one of many ways to make calls to REST APIs such as the Forge AR/VR Toolkit. You can make these calls from other 3rd party applications, or from your own code.

In case of the AR/VR Toolkit, you can obtain the list of scenes available for a specific model URN using the [GET /arkit/v1/{urn}/scenes](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/1.2.1#/ARVR-Toolkit/get_scenes) endpoint.

Comment: @Petra Broz I haven't done anything like this before using a REST API call.  I am not sure how to use this in Unity.

Comment: There are probably various HTTP clients for .NET, for example, https://restsharp.dev. You could use it to make HTTP calls directly from your Unity application. Just keep in mind that in order to communicate with the AR/VR Toolkit server, you must have a Forge "access token". For more details on that, see https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-2-legged-token.

Comment: Yep,  I am all set up with Forge and BIM 360.  It's just the calls I am not familiar with.

Comment: @Petra Broz  On that swagger site I am trying to enter my urn (just to test it) and it is saying invalid value.  The urn I am using is from the BIM 360 url of the model is that accurate?  I am also formating it to Base64.  Is there any tutorials that you know of that can show me the correct way to do a REST api call from within Unity to do this?  I can't find anything showing how I can do a WebRequest to get it done in Unity alone.  only using something like swagger or postman.

Comment: @Petra Broz  I am using postman just to get familiar with it and to see the data I can get with it.  I still can't find the scene ID needed to grab the model in the Forge Unity toolkit.  i looked in the documentation and the developers guide but see nothing about it.  unless I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: What exactly do you see when you make the request I mentioned in the answer? Do you get a 200 OK response with no data, or do you get a 4XX status code?

Comment: I am getting data using postman.  I am only using postman to help me learn how to do this.  Then I want to move it into Unity with a web request.  Right now I am using the "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/...." in Postman and getting simple data but not able to get past the folder_id.  And your first response your using the "GET/arkit/v1/{URN}/scenes"  I don't understand that end point.  In the documentation on the Forge site doesn't have anything going to that endpoint.  Is there a "Step by Step" tutorial for the Unity Forge ar/vr toolkit

Comment: We've recently published a blog post, re-explaining how the AR/VR toolkit can be used: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/arvr-toolkit-refresher. Please give it a try.

Comment: Yes,  I was all over that.  So I have to create a server with a viewer to be able to grab the model in Unity?

Comment: It was my understanding that I would be able to bring models into Unity using the Unity Forge toolkit and grab them directly from BIM 360.

Comment: No, you don't need to create a custom server application. The blog post just explains the different REST endpoints you need to call to prepare your scene for Unity.

Comment: You would have to find the specific _version_ of a document in BIM360 Docs that you're interested in (this [tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/) explains that), and encode its ID (it should start with something like `urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:...`) with base64. That's your URN.

Comment: I got that.  But it isn't working. I'm getting the 422 error if I put the file name as the scene ID.  If I leave the scene ID blank it says it loaded in 1.xxxx ms but does not show up.

Comment: In that case I'd ask you to send all the details (client ID, client secret, file URN, the exact form of the requests you are making to the toolkit server, etc.) to our official email alias `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, so that we could investigate the issue on our end. We will not share the information with anyone outside of our team.

Comment: I got it working....or it decided to work by itself.  I kept trying, but I am getting an error now:  MissingComponentException: There is no 'MeshRenderer' attached to the "mesh-2-1246-770:0" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a MeshRenderer to the game object "mesh-2-1246-770:0". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

Comment: I think the Unity plugin can sometimes generate a scene node without any mesh, for example, when the Forge model contains something unusual (like line geometry). But it shouldn't prevent the scene in Unity from being populated.

Comment: It is a NWC file that is throwing the error.  Is it possible that the model isn't fully converted yet?  Like I am trying to load it prematurely?

Comment: I don't think that's the case (although you can check the status of the post-processing using this endpoint: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/1.2.1#/ARVR-Toolkit/assets_manifest).

Comment: Since this seems to be a very specific issue, I'd suggest that you book a 30min zoom call via https://calendly.com/autodeskforge, either with myself, or with my colleague Cyrille, and we would be happy to investigate the issue with you live.

Comment: Petr,  using the manifest endpoint I was able to see the progress and that’s what it was.  The model was not finished processing and I was trying to access it.  So I am good to go.  Thank you for your help.